# How to put a unique database constrain correctly – using Alter Table or in JPA annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, openjpa

I work with MySQL/OPENJPA. I have a task to impose uniqueness in one of the table columns.  From what I see I can do this in 2 ways.

1. Use `Alter Table <table name>  ADD UNIQUE <column name>`

OR

2. Using JPA annotation: `@Table(name="<table name>", uniqueConstraints=@Unique(columnNames="<column name>"))`

Which way is correct? Or maybe using both at the same time?

Comment: If the Table has already been created, perhaps you have to do it by deleting duplicates and adding the unique constraint. Otherwise set it up on the annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA annotation will be only used during generation of new db schema (so only if your persistence.xml has ddl-generation create-tables or drop-and-create).
It doesn't effect existing tables nor it is checked by JPA.

So if your DB already exists you need to use ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the DB using hibernate you can add the annotation, if you're managing it manually, use the alter table.

If you have to manage migrations on production, I'd consider to use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), which allows you to store descriptions of database changes in the version control system.